# How create Custom cursor

Tags: css

How I can create Custom cursor like this image

img:

[image]

I do like this but i do not know add cricle animation around it

```
 * {
     cursor: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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),auto;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have to use `'` in URL.

```
 * {
     cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'),auto;
}
```